Tengo este error: TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'data' of object '[object ImageData]' En Angular al implementar heatmap.js
Estoy tratando de implementar heatmap.js en mi proyecto de Angular CLI. Ya instale todo correctamente, pero al momento de realizar la configuración tengo este error: TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'data' of object '[object ImageData]'
Este es el componente de angular y después se muestra el HTML:
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, AfterViewInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import { PanelControlService } from './panel-control.service';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import * as h337 from 'heatmap.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-panel-control',
  templateUrl: './panel-control.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./panel-control.component.css']
})
export class PanelControlComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {

  @ViewChild('heatmapContainer', { static: true }) heatmapContainer!: ElementRef;

  private intervalId: any;

  alertType: string = '';
  alertMessage: string = '';

  constructor(private panelService: PanelControlService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    const heatmapInstance = h337.create({
      container: this.heatmapContainer.nativeElement,
      radius: 50,
      maxOpacity: 0.6,
      minOpacity: 0.1,
      blur: 0.75
    });

    // Example data for heatmap
    const points = [
      { x: 300, y: 90, value: 100 },
      { x: 330, y: 80, value: 50 },
      { x: 250, y: 100, value: 80 },
      { x: 400, y: 200, value: 20 },
      { x: 250, y: 250, value: 10 },
    ];

    const data = {
      max: 100,
      min: 0,
      data: points
    };

    heatmapInstance.setData(data);

  }
}



<div #heatmapContainer style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>




y bienvenido a stackoverflow en Español!
Por tu tipo de error creo que falta algo dentro de tu template, me parece que el heatmapContainer busca dentro de si un layer para renderizar cosas, algo así:
<div id="heatmapContainer">
  <!-- Overlay is for the backgorund. You can even add image instead -->
  <div class="overlay"></div> 
</div>

encontré un ejemplo funcional que quizas te ayude de guía.
post: https://dev.to/idrisrampurawala/integrating-heatmap-js-with-mouse-over-click-in-angular-56ga
repoGithub Ejemplo: https://github.com/idris-rampurawala/angular-heatmapjs
